# Solving an implicit first-order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, integrating-factor

We have a problem stating:

> Solve $ y(6y^2-x-1)dx + 2xdy = 0 $

Since we can't simply separate the variables. Our theory state we can use theses formulas to find a factor that's only dependent on a single variable:

[image]

But trying both cases gives us Integrating factors that is dependent on two variables:

Case 1: $ f(x) = \frac {-(x-3(6y^2-1))}{2x} $

Case 2: $ g(y) = \frac {x-3(6y^2-1)}{(x-6y^2+1)y} $

We're not sure what to do next or if we even used the correct method for solving this.

---

EDIT:
Here's the [full solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNeOm.png) using the accepted answer from @user577215664.

Comment: Have you tried a substitution like $y=1/u$, $y=x/u$, or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$y(6y^2-x-1)dx + 2xdy = 0$$
$$-2xy'=y(6y^2-x-1) $$
$$2xy'=y(x+1)-6y^3 $$
This is [Bernoulli's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). Maybe you have seen how to solve this specific DE in your course ?

Comment: I belive this is what our teacher wanted us to use. Thanks! I will attempt to solve it this way.

Comment: You're welcome @VoidDark

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which relies on trial and error, looking for substitutions which appear likely to simplify the equation.  First, to get rid of the $y^2$, substitute
$$u=y^2\ ,\quad \frac{du}{dx}=2y\,\frac{dy}{dx}$$
and do the algebra carefully to get
$$(6u-x-1)+\frac{x}{u}\,\frac{du}{dx}=0\ .$$
Now substitute $v=u/x$ and simplify to give
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=v-6v^2\ .$$
This is separable so I think I can leave it to you from here.  My final answer was
$$y^2(1+6Ae^x)=Axe^x\ .$$